# Wireless dropouts or rebooting requires modprobe

Tags: wireless, realtek, modprobe, disconnect

I'm trying linux for the first time in years so I've very rusty in terminology. I've managed to get my wireless pci card working, but it has random dropouts that prevent the card from working until I do a

```
sudo modprobe rtl8821ae
```

This also occurs should I perform a reboot. Before I managed to get the wireless working there were no blocking drivers. Do I need to edit a configuration file somewhere to load the driver on boot? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo rtl8812ae  >>  /etc/modules
exit
```

Now does it work as expected?

This instructs the system to load the module rtl8812ae automatically on boot. If there are still dropouts, check the logs:

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e wlan -e rtl | tail -n20
```

Paste the result here and give us the link in your reply: http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Just for learning purposes what does this do? Also I've done it, I'll mark your answer as correct if the dropout stops.

Comment: Please see my edit.